# Display WooCommerce order item custom meta data only in Admin New order notification

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, metadata, email-notifications

I have a huge problem to solve a below case. Can you help me, please?

**What I need to do:**

1. I needed to create an additional product custom field like technical specification (tech_spec), which would be filled by administrator during creating/editing a product, so I use ACF plugin.
2. These technical informations are reserved only for administrator, so I don't want to show it to customer, however I need to add them automatically to orders panel (backend) during creating a new order by clients, as well as send them only to administrator in a new order notification (email).

**What I've tried to do:**

1. I created a **tech_spec** field using a ACF plugin and displayed it on the single product edit page.
2. I implemented this field's data on the single product page using the hook: **woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button** and used css to hide them.

   **PHP (functions.php):**

```
add_action('woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button','techspec_field');

function techspec_field(){
    global $product;
    ob_start(); ?>
        <div class="techspec-info">
            <textarea name="tech_spec"><?php the_field('tech_spec'); ?></textarea>
        </div>
    <?php
    $content = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_flush();
    return $content;
}
```

**CSS (style.css):**

```
.techspec-info textarea {
display: none !important;
visibility: hidden;}
```

3. I created a function to adding a field's data to the cart.

```
add_filter('woocommerce_add_cart_item_data','techspec_add_item_data', 10,3);

function techspec_add_item_data($cart_item_data, $product_id, $variation_id)
{
    if(isset($_REQUEST['tech_spec']))
    {
        $cart_item_data['tech_spec'] = sanitize_text_field($_REQUEST['tech_spec']);
    }

    return $cart_item_data;
}
```

4. Next I implemented another function to display a data in a cart and checkout page.

```
add_filter('woocommerce_get_item_data','techspec_add_item_meta',10,2);

function techspec_add_item_meta($item_data, $cart_item)
{

    if(array_key_exists('tech_spec', $cart_item))
    {
        $custom_details = $cart_item['tech_spec'];

        $item_data[] = array(
            'key'   => 'Technical Specification',
            'value' => $custom_details
        );
    }

    return $item_data;
}
```

5. After that I created a function to adding data to new order.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_create_order_line_item', 'techspec_add_custom_order_line_item_meta', 10,4 );

function techspec_add_custom_order_line_item_meta($item, $cart_item_key, $values, $order)
{

    if(array_key_exists('tech_spec', $values))
    {
        $item->add_meta_data('Technical Specification', $values['tech_spec']);
    }
}
```

Up to this moment everything works fine, but tech_spec field's data are sending to all recipients, including customers. How to restrict sending these data only to administrator? I mean a new order notification. I will be gratefull if you want to help me.

I've tried use different solutions like **if($sent_to_admin)**, as well as hide these data using **woocommerce_order_item_get_formatted_meta_data**, but it doesn't work, or I did something wrong. Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will not be able to target **only** admin new order email notification, for order items custom meta data.

Now to make this custom order item meta data only visible on Admin single order pages, you will need to alter the "meta key" in your last function, replacing it with a slug starting with an underscore, something like `_tech_spec`, it will be hidden from customer and email notifications:

```php
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_create_order_line_item', 'techspec_add_custom_order_line_item_meta', 10,4 );

function techspec_add_custom_order_line_item_meta($item, $cart_item_key, $values, $order)
{

    if(array_key_exists('tech_spec', $values))
    {
        $item->add_meta_data('_tech_spec', $values['tech_spec']);
    }
}
```

If you want to have a readable "meta key" name replacement on Admin orders, you will use:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_item_display_meta_key', 'filter_order_item_display_meta_key', 10, 3 );
function filter_order_item_display_meta_key( $display_key, $meta, $item ) {
    // only on Admin
    if ( is_admin() && $display_key === '_tech_spec' ) {
        $display_key = __('Technical Specification', 'woocommerce');
    }
    return $display_key;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. So there is no solution to send these informations only to admin new order notifications or if I use your code I will be able to send them using a code if($sent_to_admin)?

Comment: Or maybe there is another way to implement these information than custom field? The problem is that our product technical specification changes very often (sometimes it's only the one parameter, that's why I don't wanna create another product), so I need to know a technical details for each of orders, especially if in the future customer will be use a guaranty.

Comment: Works for order meta data, but NOT for **order item** meta data; So NOT possible.
What you can do is to add this order item (product) information in a separated html table using for example `woocommerce_email_order_meta` hook, targeting admin notifications using `$sent_to_admin` or `$email` function arguments (using `$email->id`). You can choose a convenient hook in `admin-new-order.php` template file.

Comment: Thank you so much for all of your advices. Finally all works wonderful and I achieved what I wanted.

Comment: So a very good day! :)